# How to use @ as a class name with Razor Syntax for TailwindCss

Tags: razor, tailwind-css, container-queries

TailwindCss Container Queries prefix with a @ ...but also that's how we reference things in Razor syntax.

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-container-queries

How can I use container query syntax in C# asp.net .cshtml razor files?

Example

```
 class="@container"
```

Throws an exception that 'The name container does not exist in the current context'

Comment: Can you use `@@container`?

Comment: That seems to be the recommended escape method, but my compiler in VS2022 doesn't seem to understand that escape syntax.  The only thing I can get to work is class="@("@container")" and I hate that SO MUCH.